# Increment a variable string & Multi fstream open c++

Tags: c++

How can I increment a string variable in C++?
My problem is: I want to open Multi Files (`OUT1.txt`, `OUT2.txt`,...) and search inside those files, but I can't create file's names for `fstream` (exactly .*open*.....) !

My idea is :

```
void Browser(){
    int N = 4 ; // Number of files
    vector <string> S;
    string A;
    stringstream L;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        L<<"OUT"<<i<<".txt";
        A = L.str();
        File.open(A.c_str()); 
        //.......
        //.......
    }
}
```

But when i check A (cout A;)
I found this:

> OUT0.txt
>   OUT0.txtOUT1.txt
>   OUT0.txtOUT1.txtOUT2.txt
>   OUT0.txtOUT1.txtOUT2.txtOUT3.txt

And it should take just one term! Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each time in the loop, you are appending more content to the same `std::stringstream`.

Move the declaration of `std::stringstream L` inside your `for` loop, so that on each iteration you end up instantiating a new, empty, `std::stringstream`.